# how to insert rows from a csv to specific columns in an existing table in postgres+python?

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, flask

I am new to python specifically flask and working on a personal web app
i am getting a csv file from a user in my html code, and i want to read every row, and insert specific cells from this row, to specific columns in en existing table in postgres, using python panda flask.

getting this error

**IndexError: string index out of range**

my code is this

```
    bkfile = request.files['bk_file']
    conn = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost dbname=saveory user=user 
    password=pass")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    df=pd.read_csv(bkfile)
    for row in df:
        if not row[5]:
            query = ("INSERT INTO main_table(column2, column4, column5, column6) VALUES (row[1], row[3], row[6], 'charge')")
            cur.execute(query)
        if not row[6]:
            query = ("INSERT INTO main_table(column2, column4, column5, column6) VALUES (row[1], row[3], row[5], 'credit')")
            cur.execute(query)
conn.commit()
```

tnx for you help !

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference an element in a list/string unless such an element exists - i.e  `row[5]` will throw an exception unless there are at least 6 elements in row.

You probably mean something like: `if len(row) < 6`

Comment: thank you for your help. by row[5], i want the content of the 5th column of the current row. is this syntex not right ?